# How can I add color to the rows based on the group of column values using Ag Grid in Angular?

Tags: angular8, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a requirement to add colors to the rows based on group of column values as shown below in the screenshot using AG Grid in Angular. I do not want to use row group feature here. I want to add a color for the value Test1 and different color for value Test2. The values can be dynamic. How can I achieve it?

I am using Ag grid Version 22.

[image]

Comment: use ng-if in td tag

Comment: I do not have access to td as this is an ag-grid feature ! the table, columns and data will be generated by the Ag Grid component.

Comment: Use the [Cell Style](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styles/) feature from ag-grid.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. I checked CellStyle but they are applying colors based on some values. I have dynamic values like Test1, Test2 , Test3 etc. I should be able to apply the color based on these values dynamically without hardcoding.

Comment: @Nithin you can specify conditions in [Cell Style](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styles/) based on params.value to color that cell else you can use [Row Style](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/#row-style) to color the complete row

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. I will not be able to put the conditions as the values are be dynamic but they will be in a group like the screenshot shown above. They can be any one out of 300 values.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly then you want to color the row based on the value present in column2 of your grid. For that you can do something like:

```
gridOptions.rowClassRules: {
    'green': 'data.Column2 == "Test1"',
    'amber': 'data.Column2 == "Test2"',
    'red': 'data.Column2 == "Test3"'
}
```

```
gridOptions.getRowClass = getRowClass;
}

function getRowClass(params){
  switch(params.data.Column2){
    case 'Test1':
    return 'green1';
    case 'Test2':
    return 'green2';
    case 'Test3':
    return 'green3';
    case 'Test4':
    return 'red';
    ..
    ..
    default:
    return '';
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution. I will not be able to put the conditions like these because the values like Test1, Test2  are dynamic. They can be any one out of 300 values.

Comment: got it! but you have to define logic somewhere right?

Comment: I guess he wants different colors for all unique values. Probably possible to put value/color in a map, later reuse color if value is already in the map otherwise use a new color

Comment: I agree @JaqenH'ghar. that's what I am saying that he needs to put a lookup /map kind of logic somewhere from which a function can return color value based on cell value.